# Mapping of two Delivery receipts of a concatenated Message over SMPP

Tags: sms, concatenation, smpp

I want to send a concatenated message with 3 parts. So after delivery I will get 3 Delivery receipts(DLRs). Is there a way in SMPP or by using any other methods, to understand that all these DLRs belong to a message sent to the same Mobile Number?

Answer (score 0):

Delivery receipts have the following property:

- The destination of the original message should be the source address on receipt.
- The source of the original message will become the destination address on receipt.

This behavior does not have any relationship with segmented messages.

From your comments, it seems that your app is sending submit_sm. In sumbit_sm_resp, the first field in the body is message_id (SMPP 3.4 spec, section 4.4.2). According to SMPP 3.4 spec appendix B, the short_message field of the delivery receipt reports back this message_id again. Thus, it provides a way to link the delivery receipt to the original message.

Note: short_message field on the delivery receipt follows certain format. Read SMPP 3.4 spec appendix B to know specifics.

Comment: Hello, Yes, We are aware of that, but our Real problem lies in Billing these messages together.

Comment: Hello, Yes, We are aware of that, but our Real problem lies in Billing these messages together.
From the 3 packets Submit, Submit response, and DLR how can we understand all 3 are belonging to same message!

Comment: Can you please update the question to reflect the actual problem? I am updating the answer.

Comment: Hi Wahid, Thanks for your comment. I will Explain the problem again
I have a long message, which I have to submit in 3 Parts. So after submission and Delivery, I will get 3 DLRs. 
As you mentioned I can map each of these DLRs to 3 submits for 3 parts.
But how can we know, actually all these 3 parts belong to a single message?

Comment: See my answer to the question; it tells how to pair a delivery receipt to a message. SMPP does not provide any built-in way know that 3 parts belong to a single message; it can solved by keeping track of things in some sort of DB. Hint: (1) Use multiple maps to keep track of things. (2) Think how the recipient combines the segmented messages and that will help you devise a solution. (3) Delivery receipts can take forever to come back. You may want to build some sort of timeout mechanism.